# Data is not copied in the same row (multiple workbooks to master sheet)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA routine to copy selected cells from multiple workbooks to one master file. But it has the problem that, there are possibilities that one or more of the source (input) workbooks will contain empty cell(s). So, when the data from subsequent inputs are copied, instead of being in the same row, it will move up to fill the all the blank column. Sorry if my words are not clear; English isn’t my first language. I attached an example here:

Input

```
        B3    B4     B5     B6      C9
book1   bb   1234    cc
book2   ff   3242    ff
book3   fjn  7643    jk    fjnnD   fjnnE
book4   gwd  9754    jk    gjwdD   gjwdE
```

Expected Result (in the master file)

```
        A     B      C      D       E
Row 1   bb   1234    cc     
Row 2   ff   3242    ff     
Row 3   fjn  7643    jk    fjnnD   fjnnE
Row 4   gwd  9754    jk    gjwdD   gjwdE
```

Result that I get

```
        A     B      C      D       E
Row 1   bb   1234    cc    fjnnD   fjnnE
Row 2   ff   3242    ff    gjwdD   gjwdE
Row 3   fjn  7643    jk    
Row 4   gwd  9754    jk
```

Here is my code.
It includes logic to scan a directory for input files.
That is working correctly, so you can ignore it.
The problem lies in the code to copy data
from one selected (opened) workbook
to the “Master List” sheet in the active workbook
(referenced as `SummWb`).

```
Sub UploadData()

Dim SummWb As Workbook
Dim SceWb As Workbook

'Get folder containing files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    On Error GoTo Error_handler
    myFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    'Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo 0
End With

If Right(myFolderName, 1) <> "\" Then myFolderName = myFolderName & "\"
'Settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Set SummWb = ActiveWorkbook
'Get source files and append to output file
mySceFileName = Dir(myFolderName & "*.*")

Do While mySceFileName <> "" 'Stop once all files found
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & mySceFileName
    Set SceWb = Workbooks.Open(myFolderName & mySceFileName) 'Open file found
    With SummWb.Sheets("Master List")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B4").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B5").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B6").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C9").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D9").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C10").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D10").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("C11").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("D11").Value
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SummWb.Sheets("Upload Survey").Range("C8").Value
    End With
    SceWb.Close (False) 'Close Workbook
    mySceFileName = Dir
Loop
MsgBox ("Upload complete.")
'Settings and save output file
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar
SummWb.Activate
SummWb.Save 'save automaticallly
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Error_handler:
MsgBox ("You cancelled the action.")

End Sub
```

I am guessing the problem is with the `End(xlUp)` code. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do all files have has same structure including Header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re quite right — the `End(xlUp)` method
effectively finds the last non-blank cell *in each column.* 
So, in your artificial example,
the last non-blank cell in Columns `A`, `B` and `C` is Row 4,
but the last non-blank cell in Columns `D` and `E` is Row 2. 
You want to find the last *row* where there is (non-blank) data, across all columns.

There may be a quick and easy way of doing this,
and, if so, I would like to learn it. 
But here is a somewhat brute-force way of doing it:

First, define an integer variable called `maxrow`:

```
Dim maxrow As Integer
```

(Actually, you don’t need to do this, but it’s good form.)

Then, find the last row that contains (non-blank) data in any column
simply by looking at all the columns and taking the maximum. 
At the beginning of your `With SummWb.Sheets("Master List")` block, do

```
    maxrow = 0
    maxrow = Application.Max(maxrow, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    maxrow = Application.Max(maxrow, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    maxrow = Application.Max(maxrow, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    maxrow = Application.Max(maxrow, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
      ︙
```

And so on for the other seven columns you are using. 
Then do

```
    .Cells(maxrow + 1, "A") = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B3").Value
    .Cells(maxrow + 1, "C") = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B4").Value
    .Cells(maxrow + 1, "D") = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B5").Value
    .Cells(maxrow + 1, "E") = SceWb.Sheets("Survey").Range("B6").Value
             ︙
```

And so on for the other seven columns / values. 
Quick notes:

- The `+ 1` (in `maxrow + 1`) takes the place of the `.Offset(1, 0)`,
  so you copy into the row *below* the last row
  (rather than overwriting the data in the last row).
- As far as I can tell, you don’t need the `.Value` member
  on either side of the assignment. 
  I left the ones on the right-hand side
  because I didn’t need to change the right-hand side at all. 
  If you feel adventurous, try removing them. 
  If you find a reason why you need them on the left-hand side
  (for example, `.Cells(maxrow + 1, "A").Value = …`),
  put them back in (and let me know why you needed to).

Comment: Hi Scott. Thank you for the input, another user showed me the easier way, where you need to only use .End(xlUp) once and declared it for the column where there will be no blank cells. you can refer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845767/copying-data-from-multiple-workbook-to-one-masterfile-data-not-entered-in-the-s/52846910#52846910 thank you, for your help, i still learn new knowledge based on your input :)

Comment: In case it wasn’t clear, that answer assumes that cell `B3` in the source sheets (which gets copied to Column `A` in the master sheet) is ***never*** blank. Otherwise, it will overwrite information.

Comment: Hi Scott, in my case, B3 will never be blank. D9, D10, and D11 will sometimes be blank.

Comment: Well, then, you’re probably OK. (For future reference, if you know facts like that about your data set, it can be helpful to mention them in your question.)